# Encounter an error while upgrading to Ubuntu 22.10 from Ubuntu 22.04 - Oct 20

Tags: networking, upgrade

I encounter a network error while upgrading Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10 today, the first day of release.
[image: network error message]
[image]

Please help,  thanks .

Comment: The process stops at "Setting up New Software Channels"  - step 2

Comment: How to get rid of this error:

Err http://job.ubuntuce.com ./ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4FC90FFF9C6B7E15

Comment: Then I try:
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4FC90FFF9C6B7E15

Return Message:
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.wvtJn3E21A/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4FC90FFF9C6B7E15
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data

Comment: I am getting closer in solving this problem... any insights from the community?

Answer (score 1):

Someone suggested me the following, and it works;
https://docs.ubuntuce.com/how-to/fix-repo

Add UbuntuCE Repo Key

wget https://job.ubuntuce.com/KEY.gpg && gpg --output ubuntuce.gpg --dearmor KEY.gpg && sudo mv ubuntuce.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/ && rm KEY.gpg

Update Packages

sudo apt update

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).